# Pandas to_sql method work with sqlalchemy hana connector?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm creating a sqlalchemy engine (have pyhdb and sqlalchemy-hana installed) for a HANA db connection and passing it into pandas' to_sql function for dataframes:

```
hanaeng = create_engine('hana://username:password@host_address:port')
my_df.to_sql('table_name', con = hanaeng, index = False, if_exists = 'append')
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (pyhdb.exceptions.DatabaseError) invalid column name
```

I created a table in my Hana schema that matches the column names and type of what I'm trying to pass into it from the dataframe.

Has anyone ever come across this error? Or tried connecting to hana using a sqlalchemy engine? I tried using a pyhdb connector to make a connection object and passing that into to_sql but I believe pandas is trying to shift accepting only sqlalchemy engine objects in to_sql versus straight DBAPI connectors? Regardless, any help will be great! Thank you

Comment: Does it work if you write it to a new table ? (so don't create it in advance: `my_df.to_sql('table_name_other', con=hanaeng, index=False)`)

Comment: @joris it does work when I create a new table - is this unusual or a undocumented aspect of using to_sql? I figured that the "if_exists" arg would just append since the table exists in the DB.

This script will be running on a daily basis with the query changing on which dates will be selected. HANA tools don't work with the DB where we're storing the data, hence the need for this script. The other option I was considering was brute force iterating through each row in the df and calling an "INSERT" sql statement using the connection object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does work for sure.

Your problem is that `my_df` contains a column name that does not match any column in HANA table you are trying to insert data.